# In linux, I want to listen for changes within a directory tree, and backup files if they are changed

Tags: linux

If there's any change in `~/mydir`, I want to copy it to `~/someotherdir/mydir_revisions/04-02-2013` (which is today's date). It should continue to copy to this same directory for 1 week. Thereafter, it should create a new directory (`~/someotherdir/mydir_revisions/04-09-2013`, which is that day's date and continue using that directory for a week). These backups would continue indefinitely, always utilizing a particular date for a whole week before updating the date.

If it matters, I'm using Archlinux and copying to a different filesystem. How can I do this with **incron** or any other recommended package?

Comment: Are you comfortable with any scripting language? Bash or Perl or similar?

Comment: I'd like to suggest using inotifywait for this; have used it on several occasions in the past, works a treat.

Comment: @terdon, I prefer Python, but I'd be willing to learn Bash if need-be

Comment: Which ever route you're going to go down, I'd like to point out that neither incron, inotifywait or either of the two python implementations I'm aware of will stand up recursive watches for newly created subdirectories automatically - just a small caveat.

Comment: Have you considered using a version control system like git? You'd get a record of the changes too.

Comment: @parkydr git has a learning curve on its own, and I'm trying to focus on the actual project at hand. But yes, git would definitely be ideal if I knew how to use it already.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your distribution, there is the package `incrond`.

What this package does is, it receives filesystem events from the kernel via `inotify`.

Your setup would be something as:

```
/path/to/monitored/directory IN_MODIFY /path/to/script/to/execute
```

Let's say you have the following script in `$HOME/incron-move.sh`, with does the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
WEEK_OF_YEAR=`date +"%W"`
cp -ar $HOME/mydir /other/dir/mydir_revisions/$WEEK_OF_YEAR
```

What this script does, is to copy the full contents of `/path/to/monitored/directory` to `/other/dir/mydir_revisions/13` if it were to run today (02/04/2013 it's in the 13th week of the year)

It isn't the full requirement of yours, but solves your problem with some degree of reliability.

Comment: I'm aware of that package. I'm looking to do something more specific than copying to a directory upon change. I want to include a date, as described in the question.

Comment: @Raj date supports alot of options (eg. +%Y-%m-%d). Also, there is likely a Python inotify interface-module.